# Best way to describe C++ program using charts

Tags: c++, documentation

I'm currently writing a developper documentation of a program I just wrote and which has to be continued by somebody else.
I'm documenting my code using Doxygen, but I'd like to show a more global view, using for instance flow charts filled with the name of the functions and the parameters they send to each other. But I also have to represent events, and it seems to me that flow charts are not the best for that, or a least I don't really see how to do it right and clear.

So **Am I right? What would *you* need to catch on with a development of an already started application? Is there a better alternative than flow charts and UML?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a general *familiarisation* perspective, I like seeing clear and detailed requirements specifications. This is lacking in the majority of cases in my experience.

From a *design* perspective, I like seeing **state diagrams** for state transitions, **UML diagrams** for general code structure and relationships and **communication diagrams** for information about data flows.

The more documentation you can give, the better it'll be for *the next guy*. But bear in mind that documentation can go out-of-date very quickly, so your (good) **code comments** and **doxygen output** are likely (but not necessarily so) to be more up-to-date than anything else you write.

Comment: That's very interesting! I don't think I would need an UML diagram as I'm working on really small project (only one week and a half with two guys) so I don't have thousands of classes. But the communication and state diagrams are more likely to display how the program works, so I will certainely use those ones!

Answer (score 0):

As someone who picked up a 35,000 line Java project with 3 comments 2 of which were "this is gross" and "yeesh" I can say that I want to know what the abstract base classes are, what the flow of the program is, and any namespaces or global variables defined.

What's really helpful to me is a paragraph or two that says something along the lines of "main creates a driver of some base class which then reads in the xml file using some file reader and sets up an output object of type DefaultOutput before it executes the driver.run() function which ostreams the std:out to a file called output.txt and std::err to log.txt.

That paragraph would save me hours of picking through your code to figure out what gets used all the time.

It's also really helpful to have a "this depends on this so don't change it or you'll ruin literally everything" for any finicky code that might be present.

Comment: I understand! My program is not THAT long, but I'll try to write down some of the basic structure elements so the next guy will have somewhere to strat pretty smoothly.